# Improve Prediction Accuracy of Keras Neural Network Algorithm

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

How can I modify my code below to improve its current accuracy of 71.38%? The dataset is 6 independant variables of numbers and 1 dependant variable of either 0 or 1.

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
dataset = loadtxt('numbers/numbers.csv', delimiter=',')
X = dataset[:,0:6]
y = dataset[:,6]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=6, activation='softsign'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='softsign'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softsign'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='SGD', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, batch_size=100)
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
predictions = model.predict_classes(X)
for i in range(5):
    print('%s => %d (expected %d)' % (X[i].tolist(), predictions[i], y[i]))
```

Comment: You can add a dropout layer between any of your Dense layers to help improve your accuracy. Try testing out different loss functions like "relu" or "softmax".

Comment: A model's performance is based on a number of factors including the data. It will be helpful if you could provide insights into your data and the task which you are performing.

Comment: @RichardX, I'm not familiar with how to add a dropout layer, can you give me some clue or reference?

Comment: `from keras.layers import Dropout`. This allows you to use the dropout layer like any other layer. `model.add(Dropout(0.25))`. This just specifies the fraction of units that will be dropped.